# How to run cronjob in azure cloud bash shell

Tags: azure, cron, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to run cron job in azure cloud shell
but it is not working

This is my simple cron job

```
* * * * *  /home/meet/clouddrive/temp.sh
```

where

```
cat /home/meet/clouddrive/temp.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "meet" >> /home/meet/clouddrive/test.txt
```

```
pwd
/home/meet/clouddrive
```

```
meet [ ~/clouddrive ]$ ls
temp.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I tried to run Cron job in azure cloud shell like below:

when I try **`crontab -l`** there is no job from here.

[image]

Then create **`crontab -e`**

Run **`*/1 * * * * echo "this is a test" /home/imran123/testfile.txt`**

Then try to create a file using **`vi testfile.txt`** and I mention **"This is test"**

Then try to give execute permission like below:

**`chmod +x test.sh`**

[image]

Then when I executed cmd  it run successfully like below:

```json
crontab -l
cat testfile.txt
```

[image]